# Using Titanium Appcelerator is there a way to access downloads or shared documents folder on ios

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

Is there a way in Titanium Appcelerator to read/write file in downloads folder or shared documents folder.
As per appcelerator documentation: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Filesystem_Access_and_Storage
**Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory** can only accessible by app itself. 
I add file in app's Document folder using

`var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(timelogsData,'timelogs.txt');f.write(data);`

then try to access by iExplorer and other file manager but no luck. I could only read it by my app only.

As per Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28 app's documents folder data can be shared.

*My objective is that, my app need internet access if internet is not available then it will save data into a file that end user can send me manually or by email.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Guys, can anybody help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. You could implement the email part inside your app to so you can access all the files you saved with the same app. It will open the normal Mail from your ios device, so you can create the email offline and it will send it when you have internet again

Comment: Thanks @miga yes we can be used, but I am focusing to get file. Files inside app's Documents folder should be accessible.

Comment: Waleed, I think what the Apple docs say is that you can share files from this folder, but it doesn't say you can access the files from another app.

Comment: Thanks @Fokke-Appcelerator , yes as per Apple documentation apps Documents folder contents can be shared, but, when I create a file from Appcelerator inside app's Document it is not syncing or sharing. I install iExplorer and try to explore file but iExplorer showing emply folder, while same file is accessible by my app. Is there a way that I can create a file inside Downloads folder using Appcelerator?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't atm. It woud make a great (and probably simple) feature request though! Please check if it has already been requested at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it has not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide a complete description in the ticket. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Thanks @Fokke-Appcelerator I have added a ticket, please check, https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3484 if it is fine. 

Many Thanks for your kind help.